# does a called function complete before executing next line of code in c

Tags: c, arduino

When calling a function in c (programming an arduino), will that function finish before executing the next line of code in the original function?

See comments in example below:

```
void loop()
{  
    duration = random(750, 1500);
    advertise("111", duration); // <-- will this function fully complete
    int delayDuration = random (300,500); // <--before executing this line of code?
    delay(delayDuration);
}
```

Comment: The function "advertise" must complete, yes. But it might be the case that what the advertise function does is to put something on a queue of tasks to be done later in another thread, in which case it's "job" might not be completed in that sense. Such functions are called "asynchronous", and are rare, and generally well-documented as such, but they are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Code execution in a `thread` happens sequentially. The called function should `return` and the execution shall continue from the next statement in the function that called.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely dependent on the implementation of `delay`.

If it is synchronous, as one would expect, then the call to `delay` will effectively "pause" your function for approximately `delayDuration` units of time (usually milliseconds).

The initialisation of `delayDuration` *might* complete before `advertise` is called, but `advertise` will complete before `delay` is called, and it will complete before `loop` exits.